# Calculus application question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, applications

[image]

My attempt:

Step 1: Find $x$ in terms of $t$.

- $\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{-0.15x}$
- $t = \frac{1}{-0.15}\ln(x) = x^{-1}(t)$
- $x(t) = e^{-0.15t}+c$

However, here is where I am stuck. Without any extra information about $x(t)$(initial conditions) to find the value of $c$, I cannot proceed further to find the value of $t$ at which the amount of drug has halved and hence, the time interval as well. Does anyone have any idea of how this could be solved?

Comment: The notation is a little confusing, which may be why the constant of integration is in the wrong place. Integrating gives $t + C = -\frac{20}{3} \ln x$ for some constant $C$, and exponentiating gives $x(t) = D e^{-3 t / 20}$ for some constant $D = x(0)$, and you'll find that the halving time doesn't depend on the initial amount $x(0)$.

Comment: Just to be more explicit about what Travis said, you have three substeps in "Step 1".  The constant of integration should be added in the SECOND substep, not the third.

Answer (score 1):

That's an awkward way of working on the problem!  From dx/dt= -0.15x we can immediately get dx/x= -0.15tdt and, itegrating ln(x)= -0.15t+ C for some constant C.  Taking the exponential of both sides, x= C'e^(-0.15t) where C'= e^C.

That seems more natural to me than inverting the equation to "dt/dx" but you got that result anyway!

When t= 0, x= C'.  What  will t be when x= C'e^(-0.15t) is half that?  That is, you need to solve C'e^(-0.15t)= (1/2)C'.  Of course, you can divide both sides by C' so your problem is to solve e^(-0.15t)= 1/2.